# Isomorphic library picking of WebSocket library

Tags: node.js, browser, ecmascript-5

```
import { default as WebSocket } from 'ws';
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.document !== 'undefined';
const url = ...;
let webSocket;
const isBrowser
    ? // Browser.
      (webSocket = new global.WebSocket(url))
    : // Node.js.
      (webSocket = new WebSocket(url));
```

I get the error:

```
src/client.ts:155:48 - error TS2339: Property 'WebSocket' does not exist on type 'Global'.

155                 ? (webSocket = new global.WebSocket(url))
```

If I change it to `window.WebSocket` I get:

```
src/client.ts:156:20 - error TS2740: Type 'WebSocket' is missing the following properties from type 'WebSocket': ping, pong, terminate, on, and 14 more.

156                   (webSocket = new window.WebSocket(url))
```

I'm trying to make an isomorphic library that will work in Node.js and in the browser. How would one do this simply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was nearly correct: I needed to use `globalThis.WebSocket` instead of `global.WebSocket`.